# How to marginalise out probabilities with multiple variables?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I am trying to understand how the top equals the bottom:

[Marginalising out variables J and R in both numerator and denominator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m67fR.png)

The equations are very specific to a problem I am trying to solve and the textbook shows that these are equal. But I do not understand how they seemingly "cancel out" p(J|R) and just end up marginalising over R instead. If they can cancel out p(J|R) can they not cancel out P(R) as well? What mathematical steps are they missing?

(Edit for clarity: the states T and S are already both 1, and all variables take a binary output {0,1}.)

Comment: P(J|R) for fixed R and S that sums over J to 1 by law of total probability.

Comment: Why does that not apply to P(R) on this case?

Comment: R appears in multiple expressions, so we are not just summing P(R). J doesn't appear anywhere else, so is effectively like this: $\sum_{R,S} f(R,S) \cdot \left( \sum_J P(J|R) \right) = \sum_{R,S} f(R,S) \cdot \left(1 \right)$. For each fixed R we get 1.